# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) in React Express App

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, unauthorized

I am trying to make a service. The credentials are working fine as I have tested it using thunderclient. But in the actual application I am getting this error in console whenever I am trying to use the services through add or delete.
These are the add and delete errors that I am getting in console

```
POST http://localhost:5000/api/notes/addnote 401 (Unauthorized)      NoteState.js:27 
 
DELETE http://localhost:5000/api/notes/deletenote/undefined 401 (Unauthorized)   NoteState.js:43
```

I don't know if there are any security changes that I need to implement which will resolve this issue.

> NoteState.js

```
import NoteContext from "./noteContext";
import { useState } from "react";

const NoteState = (props) => {
  const host = "http://localhost:5000"
  const notesInitial = []
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState(notesInitial)

  // Get all Notes
  const getNotes = async () => {
    // API Call 
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/fetchallnotes`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "auth-token": localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
    });
    const json = await response.json()
    setNotes(json)
  }

  // Add a Note
  const addNote = async (title, description, tag) => {
    // TODO: API Call
    // API Call 
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/addnote`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "auth-token": localStorage.getItem('token')
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title, description, tag })
    });

    const note = await response.json();
    setNotes(notes.concat(note))
  }

  // Delete a Note
  const deleteNote = async (id) => {
    // API Call
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/deletenote/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "auth-token": localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
    });
    const json = response.json();
    console.log(json);

    const newNotes = notes.filter((note) => { return note._id !== id })
    setNotes(newNotes)
  }

  // Edit a Note
  const editNote = async (id, title, description, tag) => {
    // API Call 
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/notes/updatenote/${id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "auth-token": localStorage.getItem('token')
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ title, description, tag })
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
      

    let newNotes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(notes))
    // Logic to edit in client
    for (let index = 0; index < newNotes.length; index++) {
      const element = newNotes[index];
      if (element._id === id) {
        newNotes[index].title = title;
        newNotes[index].description = description;
        newNotes[index].tag = tag;
        break;
      }
    }
    setNotes(newNotes);
  }

  return (
    <NoteContext.Provider value={{ notes, addNote, deleteNote, editNote, getNotes }}>
      {props.children}
    </NoteContext.Provider>
  )

}
export default NoteState;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!